# Screen won't accept resolution after power outage

Tags: windows, display, resolution

I'm having a problem with my monitor after a power outage. At first I suspected video driver not loading properly because the problem is that the screen won't accept its native resolution of 1440 x 900. I made sure the video driver is working and it is. I did a check disk on all drives. It allows me to select much higher resolutions, but there is a gap right around 1440. It goes to 1366 and then jumps to 1600, skipping any option for 1440. I noticed that when Windows loaded after the outage, the screen said mode not supported for a while and then went down to 1024 or something. Makes me think it's the screen.
I tried another comp with the monitor and while I can select 1440 x 900, the display is all misaligned with bars on the side that I can't fix via monitor's settings. So I am leaning toward a problem with the monitor. I find this very odd though cause the monitor seems to be working just fine with other resolutions.

Has this ever happened to anyone? Where the monitor just no longer accepts it's normal resolution, but works fine otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, first verify that the monitor still works.

I experienced something similar. After a power outage a desktop machine running Windows 10 that had been fine for years all of a sudden could not be set to any resolution higher than 1024x768.

None of the advice online alleviated the problem e.g. reboot, update drivers, hard power down the monitor, etc. I am answering this old question just because I am not seeing anyone online document what the problem was in my case.

In my case, it turned out that monitor itself was broken, or at least HDMI input to the monitor was broken. I suspected it was the monitor and verified with a laptop from which HDMI out worked fine when connected to my TV but failed totally, i.e. black screen, when connected to this monitor. It might be the case that display port input to the monitor would have worked; I did not test this.